# Redirect not working in Ruby on Rails 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have this code

```
if (....)
   ....  
else
   flash[:error] = 'Error'
   redirect_to({ :controller => :home })
end
```

Now the flash error message works, but the redirect does not.

The server log shows the following:

```
Redirected to controllerhome
```

but there is no redirect.

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong?

EDIT

as requested, output of     rake routes | grep home

```
root/ {:controller => "home", :action => "index"}
```

I have tried the code with

```
:action => index
```

added, but no change

Comment: could you please paste the output of `rake routes | grep home` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `redirect_to({ :controller => :home })`, if you want to redirect to your home page, use this:

```
redirect_to(root_path)
```

But this implies that you have in your routes:

```
root to: 'home#your_home_page_action'
```

with `home` being your `home_controller` and `your_home_page_action` the method in this controller that takes care of the home page

Comment: I have tried it but it does the exact same thing as my initial code

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect_to({ controller: home, action: show })
```

Or read the documentation. This is for Rails 4, but I thing redirections didn't change so much.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this to redirect

```
redirect_to :controller => 'home', :action => 'show'
```

This syntax will also work to redirect one action to another action.